Jaxb - I want 'xs:nil' but don't want 'xmlns:xsi'
MyClass.java
@XmlElement(nillable=true, required=true)
public String myNillableThing;

Actual output
...
<myNillableThing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
...

Desired output
...
<myNillableThing xs:nil="true"/>
<-- note xs, not xsi -->
...

I'll be honest, I don't know what either of those attributes mean, but I am trying to produce a file which replicates a very specific example and those are the tags shown on the example file.

I suspect the example you are using for guidance is wrong. W3C owns the "xs" namespace, and W3C has not defined a name xs:nil in that namespace, and no-one else has the right to use the namespace for their own purposes.

What's a namespace in the context of an xml file? What purpose does it serve?

StackOverlfow isn't the place to ask questions about the basic concepts: you need to do some reading. Any book on XML covers this.

What you have is semantically identical to what you want, I believe.
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" defines the token xsi to be that URL. You have to define some prefix. Now, you might have a document in which you see xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" up higher in the structure, and then a reference to xs:nil down below. But someone has to define the prefix, there are no prefixed provided by default.
To an XML parser, all of this is just syntax around the pair:
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance, nil

the prefixes have no semantic value. If you are parsing XML without a true parser, and just looking literally for 'xs:nil', you are potentially in for all kinds of problems.

Thanks for your reply...
"Now, you might have a document in which you see xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" up higher in the structure"
You're exactly right, in the example file this information is in the top tag a the root of the file, but in mine it's on the nested tag. So I guess my question is actually "How do I make xmlns:xs... appear in the root tag?" I can edit/clarify the question or write a completely new one if necessary

What technology are you using to write the XML?

JAXB and EclipseLink

I can't help you with eclipselink. If you really need to control prefix declarations, you'll need to read the source of it or find another expert.
